# HTML div with left and right alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to create something that looks like this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C66Cq.png)

This is what my current code looks like:

```css
#container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #00ffff;
}

#center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:10%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #00ff00;
}

#right {
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ff00ff;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:50px"> Player1Name
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:50px">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:50px"> Player2Name
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

But I can't figure out how to align it like in the image above. Can someone please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like that ?

```css
#container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(140deg, #acecca 50%, #64D993 50.1%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.centerDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.flexLeft {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flexRight {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.centerElem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.barre {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius:20px;
}

#player1 .barre>.completed {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 10%;
  /* Progression barre joueur 1 */
  height: 100%;
}

#player2 .barre>.completed {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 60%;
  /* Progression barre joueur 2 */
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  border-radius:20px;
}

#player1 img {
  border-color: #64D993;
}

#player2 img {
  border-color: #acecca;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <div id="player1" class="left">
      <div class="centerDiv flexLeft">
        <div class="centerElem">
          <img src="https://www.norskmultiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:50px"> JANE DOE 6 SALES
        </div>
        <div class="barre">
          <div class="completed"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
      <div class="centerDiv">
        <div class="centerElem">
          <p style='font-size: 42px;'>⚔️</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="player2" class="right">
      <div class="centerDiv flexRight">
        <div class="barre">
          <div class="completed"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="centerElem">
          JOHN DOE 3 SALES
          <img src="https://www.norskmultiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:50px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Almost like that. I want the left image and text to align left side, and right image and text to align right side. Exactly like in the photo I posted :)

Comment: I modified my post, tell me if it's ok.

Comment: Is it also possible to add progress bar, like this: https://pasteboard.co/JURqgFE.png ?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66860575/add-progress-bar-to-div