# Add progress bar to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a progress bar to my current code. This is a part of what my code currently looks like:

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(140deg, #acecca 50%, #64D993 50.1%);
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}

#center {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.centerDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.flexLeft {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flexRight {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.centerElem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='left'>
    <div class='centerDiv flexLeft'>
      <div class='centerElem'>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <img alt='Avatar' src='https://www.norskmultiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/avatar.png' style='width:65px;height:65px;overflow:hidden;border: 5px solid #64D993;' /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div class='name'>JANE DOE<br>6 SALES
        </div>&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <progress id='file' value='32' max='100'></progress>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='center'>
    <div class='centerDiv'>
      <div class='centerElem'>
        <p style='font-size: 42px;'>⚔️</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='right'>
    <div class='centerDiv flexRight'>
      <div class='centerElem'>
        <div class='name'>JOHN DOE<br>3 SALES</div>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <br>
        <img alt='Avatar' src='https://www.norskmultiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/avatar.png' style='width:65px;height:65px;overflow:hidden;border: 5px solid #acecca;' /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am wondering is: How can I make the progress bar go between the name and ⚔️ icon? I tried adding width:100%; to the progress bar, but that doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: What do you mean by "make the progress bar go between the name and ⚔️ icon"? Is this just a CSS positioning question, or are you trying to edit the `progress` element to get some specific functionality? (@MisterJojo they are: `<progress id='file' value='32' max='100'></progress>`)

Comment: @MisterJojo Please look at my code. That is exactly the same as the one I have in my code...

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I want to do something like this kind of positioning: https://pasteboard.co/JUU14lp.png .

Answer (score 0):

You may use `position: ...;` to move elements around how ever you please.
To make things easier, you can use `position: ...;` in the parent container and then use `right:...; left:...; top:...;` or `bottom:...;`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
    .container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(140deg, #acecca 50%, #64D993 50.1%);
    }

    #left {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    }

    #center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    }

    #right {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    }

    img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .centerDiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .flexLeft {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    .flexRight {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .centerElem {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }

    .name {
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    .progressBar {
        position: relative;
        width: 250px;
    }
    #file2 {
       
        right: 15%;
    }
    #file1 {
        left: 15%;
    }
    </style>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='left'>
          <div class='centerDiv flexLeft'>
            <div class='centerElem'>
              <img alt='Avatar' src='https://www.norskmultiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/avatar.png' style='width:65px;height:65px;overflow:hidden;border: 5px solid #64D993;' /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <div class='name'>JANE DOE<br>6 SALES</div>
              <progress class="progressBar" id='file1' value='32' max='100'></progress>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <div id='center'>
          <div class="centerDiv">
            <div class="centerElem">
              <p style='font-size: 42px;'>⚔️</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <div id='right'>
            <div class='centerDiv flexRight'>
            <progress class="progressBar" id='file2' value='32' max='100'></progress>
              <div class='centerElem'>
                <div class='name'>JOHN DOE<br>3 SALES</div>
                <img alt='Avatar' src='https://www.norskmultiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/avatar.png' style='width:65px;height:65px;overflow:hidden;border: 5px solid #acecca;' />
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this isn't what you want let me know and I'll try to change it